# Change colour of selected cell using values in cells based off the selected cell

Tags: excel, vba, rgb

I have a macro to colour a cell based on the RGB values.
I have cells A1, B1, and C1 for the RGB values.

```vb
Sub FillWithRBG()
    Range("D1").Interior.Color = RGB(Range("A1").Value, Range("B1").Value, Range("C1").Value)
End Sub
```

I can select anywhere in the worksheet, run the macro and only cell D1 will change colour.

I want to select cell D2, run the macro and Cell D2 changes colour based off values in A2, B2, and C2.

I imagine I need to set the active cell with a reference, then 1, 2 and 3 will be offset from the selected cell.
An added bonus would be that the macro can only run in the D column to prevent errors.

Comment: You need to google the worksheet change/selection change event and then use offset to make the references relative.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be a simple approach

- In the code `Me.` is refering to the current sheet
- You have to place this code in the sheet's module

[image]

- Columns in VBA are noted by numbers (so column A is referenced as column 1)

**Code:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    
    
    ' Prevent change if changed values are no in these columns (1,2,3) numbers are equivalent to A, B, C
    If Target.Column > 3 Then Exit Sub
    
    ' Change color of D column (4 = D)
    Me.Cells(Target.Row, 4).Interior.Color = RGB(Me.Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value, Me.Cells(Target.Row, 2).Value, Me.Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value)
    
End Sub
```

- If you want it to work only if you're changing one cell at a time add these lines:

  ```
    ' Prevent change when more than one cell is changed
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  ```